# Upload file by name using webservice rest

Tags: rest, jersey, inputstream

I am using this code to upload a file

```
@Path(value= "/up")
public class upload {
public static String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER =       "C://Users/Marya/Desktop/";
@POST
@Path(value="upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,@FormDataParam("name") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + fileDetail.getFileName();
    System.out.println("*****serverpath********");
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);
    String output = "File saved to  server location : " + filePath;
    System.out.println("done");
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String serverLocation) {
    try {
    OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new  File(serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            System.out.println("*****read********");
        }
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code is working, but the name of uploaded file is "newfile" as mentioned in the path "C://Users/Marya/Desktop/newfile" . So how can I save the file by its name ??

After adding jars I get this error

**NEW ERROR**

```
Grave: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.upload.uploadFile(upload.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the file name in your post :

```
    @Path(value= "/up")
    public class upload {
    public static String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://Users//Marya//Desktop//newfile";

        @POST
        @Path(value="upload")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public Response uploadFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileIS, @FormDataParam("name") String name ) {

        //recommand to test call arguments here (null, empty) in order to throw errors
        if (name==null || fileIS==null) return Response.status(400).build();


        String location =SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER+java.io.File.separator+ name;
         System.out.println("before write ["+location+"]");
        saveFile(fileIS, location );
        String output = "File saved to  server location : " + location;
        System.out.println("file written ["+location+"]");
        return Response.ok().entity(output).build();
    }

    /**
    **/
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String serverLocation) {
        try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new  File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                System.out.println("*****read********");
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And to write a **beautifull code**, I should use `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write()` that is much better than performing your own loop for reading/writting. This would refactor saveFile() as this :

```
    /**
    * save File v2 with apache.commons.io 
    **/
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String serverLocation) {
        try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new  File(serverLocation));
          org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write(uploadedInputStream, outpuStream );
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Enjoy! :)

**UPDATED on 6/06 12:23 BRT**
Please try this code :

```
   @Path(value= "/up")
    public class upload {
    public static String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://Users//Marya//Desktop//newfile";

    @POST
    @Path(value="upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileIS,   @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail ) {

    //recommand to test call arguments here (null, empty) in order to throw errors
    if (fileDetail ==null || fileIS==null) return Response.status(400).build();


    String location =SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER+java.io.File.separator+ fileDetail.getFileName();
     System.out.println("before write ["+location+"]");
    saveFile(fileIS, location );
    String output = "File saved to  server location : " + location;
    System.out.println("file written ["+location+"]");
    return Response.ok().entity(output).build();
}
```

**UPDATED on 6/06 14:54 BRT**
Please try this code :

```
   @Path(value= "/up")
    public class upload {
    public static String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://Users//Marya//Desktop//newfile";

    @POST
    @Path(value="upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileIS,   @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail ) {

    //recommand to test call arguments here (null, empty) in order to throw errors
    if (fileDetail ==null || fileIS==null) return Response.status(400).build();


    String location =SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER+java.io.File.separator+ fileDetail.getFileName();
     System.out.println("before write ["+location+"]");
    saveFile(fileIS, location );
    String output = "File saved to  server location : " + location;
    System.out.println("file written ["+location+"]");
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jean but when I add the name as you said the file is not uploaded and I get this log : File saved to  server location : C://Users/Marya/Desktop/file------WebKitFormBoundaryShFPRSvDqzNREwzR.Plz have you any suggestions to solve that issue ??

Comment: give a try like this ;

Comment: as I modified right on the revision : UPDATED on 6/06 12:23 BRT

Comment: It is not working also I edited my post so you can see the error I get

Comment: can't see the modif on you post. Can you give me your stacktrace please

Comment: I added the error : ERROR ,you can find it just after the code

Comment: have you got jersey-multipart library in your classpath ? please install it this dependencies : jersey-server version 1.8 & jersey-multipart version 1.8. I think that multipart is missing Marya.

Comment: I added missing jars now I get a new error ( I edited again my post and you can find ther the new error : NEW ERROR ). The status Code of the webservice is 500

Comment: you're close to do it, see my last update ! the return statement was mistypped. :)